# Rest api call and POST request (java)

Tags: java, api, rest

I am pretty new concerning REST api and POST request. 
I have the url of a REST api. I need to access to this api by doing an API call in JAVA thanks to a client id and a client secret (I found a way to hash the client secret). However, as I am new I don't know how to do that api call. I did my research during this all day on internet but I found no tutorial, website or anything else about how to do an api call. So please, does anyone know a tutorial or how to do that? (if you also have something about POST request it would be great)

I would be very thankful.

Thank you very much for your kind attention.

Sassir

Comment: I would like to implement it with JAVA under eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example snippet using JDK classes only.  This might help you understand HTTP-based RESTful services a little better than using a client helper.  The order in which you call these methods is crucial.  If you have issues, add a comments with your issue and I will help you through it.

```
URL target = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnectionconn = (HttpURLConnection) target.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

// used for POST and PUT, usually
// conn.setDoOutput(true);
// OutputStream toWriteTo = conn.getOutputStream();

conn.connect();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

try 
{
    InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    InputStream error = conn.getErrorStream();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code to be suitable for https like in my case. 

But, I don't know how to use my client id and client signature headers. Do you know how to do ?

Then, to connect to an API account using an email and a password, I have to make a POST request to https://url/../ with body arguments email and password (I don't know either)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RestTemplate from Spring: https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Fast and simple solution without any boilerplate code.
Simple example:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("firstParamater", "parameterValue");
map.add("secondParameter", "differentValue");

rest.postForObject("http://your-rest-api-url", map, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Restlet framework also allows you to do such thing thanks to its class `ClientResource`. In the code below, you build and send a JSON content within the POST request:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://...");

SONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.add("entryOne", "...");
jo.add("entryTow", "...");

cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(jo), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Restlet allows to send any kind of content (JSON, XML, YAML, ...) and can also manage the bean / representation conversion for you using its converter feature (creation of the representation based on a bean - this answer gives you more details: [XML & JSON web api : automatic mapping from POJOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250862/xml-json-web-api-automatic-mapping-from-pojos/28263233#28263233)).

You can also note that HTTP provides an header `Authorization` that allows to provide authentication hints for a request. Several technologies are supported here: basic, oauth, ... This link could help you at this level: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

Using authentication (basic authentication for example) can be done like this:

```
String username = (...)
String password = (...)
cr.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, username, password); 
(...)
cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(jo), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry